# JQuery: Multiple selectors, doing something only with one of them

Tags: jquery

Hope you can help.

I'm looping through two selectors:

```
$('.div').each(function() {
    $('.selector1, .selector2 option:selected').text();
}
```

Both selectors returns plain-text and I need the output in the order of the page.

**My problem** is that whenever it is .selector2 (value from a dropdown) I need to add a < span > tag around it.
How can I do that and at the same time keep the order?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an `each()` loop against (presumably) one element? Since `#div` is an ID, there should be only one of them. Even so, your selector *inside* the `.each()` is searching the entire page.

Comment: The selector on each isn't unique. My mistake when creating a simplified example. 
It is changed now :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text()` returns plain text with no markup. You shouldn't treat this as HTML, as you imply by ‘adding `<span>`’. Otherwise, `<` and `&` characters in the text will become markup, with potential security implications. Never mix up plain-text and HTML markup.

If you must throw HTML strings about, you could use `html()` instead:

```
var html= $('.selector1, .selector2 option:selected').map(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.selector1'))
        return $(this).html();
    else
        return '<span>'+$(this).html()+'</span>';
}).get().join('');
```

But I'd prefer to use DOM-like methods:

```
target= $('#place-to-put-content');
$('.selector1, .selector2').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.selector1'))
        $target.append(document.createTextNode($(this).text()));
    else
        target.append($('<span>', {text: $(this).val()}));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The text() was a mistake when I created the example. Im of course using html() since it is html I'm creating :) 

About solution 2: Would it be better to append at the end instead of in the loop? Performance wise...

Comment: It won't make any difference, as each DOM Node is inserted into the document one-by-one either way. The same happens using `append()` to insert a stretch of HTML. It's only when you can write the *whole* `html()` of an object in one go that you can get any speedup (and even then there are cases where you don't, due to jQuery's processing trying to hide bugs). In any case, unless you have *hundreds* of `.selector1, .selector2` elements in a single parent, it's not going to matter.

Comment: Just a quick update for your great solution, you miss .get() on the first solution before join()

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

> **.wrap( wrappingElement )**
>
> wrappingElementAn HTML snippet,
>   selector expression, jQuery object, or
>   DOM element specifying the structure
>   to wrap around the matched elements.
>
> **.wrap( wrappingFunction )**
>
> wrappingFunctionA callback function
>   which generates a structure to wrap
>   around the matched elements.